# 2000 Olympiad in Informatics Question on Box

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, computer-science, contest-math, recursive-algorithms

I have an old Olympiad question on informatics.

There are 31 boxes. In each box there is one number. We know the number if and only if we open the box. We want to calculate the minimum number of boxes that must be opened to find one number that is not lower than the numbers of its neighbor boxes. The first and last boxes have one neighbor (boxes are not a ring). All other boxes have two neighbors.

I see a strange answer and it is 11. Any details or ideas are very appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the question. I don't find it here http://www.ioinformatics.org/locations/ioi00/contest/index.shtml

Comment: Dear @leonbloy, it's local Olympiad on informatics in IRAN in 2000.

Comment: I'm confused by the question, particularly the statement "not lower than its neighbors".  Are we looking for a box containing the number $N$ such that *both* neighbors contain numbers (strictly?) less than $N$ or *at least one* neighbor contains a number (strictly?) less than $N$?

Comment: @squirrel My guess is that the statement is "not [strictly] lower than [either of] its neighbors," i.e., its value is at least both of its neighbors. Although we should probably wait for OP...

Comment: Dear @squirrel, suppose in a third box we have number 13. in the forth box we have 4. in the second box we have 6. so we find third box as a maximum between two neighbors. so in 31 boxes that we know anything about the number except if we open the box, we want to find such a number with at most 11 opening.

Comment: @MounaMokhiab Are we assuming that the numbers in the boxes are $1,2,\ldots, 31$?

Comment: Dear @angryavian, it's very nice question. no the number is in arbitrary order, and just we know each number by opening the box.

Comment: @MounaMokhiab So, if the second, third, and fourth boxes each have $13$, it is ok to choose the third box as our desired box?

Comment: Dear @angryavian, in such case, we not need to open the other boxes and it's desired box. but the main challenge is how we find the number of each boxes, and how select boxes to opening and find such number with at most 11 opening.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16785/discussion-between-angryavian-and-mouna-mokhiab).

Comment: @MounaMokhiab: I think the numbering is really more of a way to get a local ordering. For example, if you re-label a random box with $N$, then you can re-label its neighboring boxes with a number in $\{N-1,N,N+1\}$ just by using the "less than, equal to, or greater than" relationship coming from the actual numbers the boxes contain.

Comment: Dear @squirrel, the number is random. when we open the box we know the number of each box and there is no order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right the problem (it's not very clear), I think it can be done with less than 11.

Hint/sketch:

Lets say that a box is *apt* if its value is greater or equal than that of its neighbours. We want to find an apt box. This is analogous to finding a local maximum of a discrete sequence

Starting from the chain $(x_{1} \cdots x_{31})$, uncover $x_{16}$ and $x_{17}$. Assume (worst case) $x_{16} \ge x_{17}$ Then we restrict our chain to $(x_{1} \cdots \overline{x_{16}})$, as it must contain one apt box. (the overlined elements correspond to the known ones). 
Then uncover $x_{8},x_{9}$ If $x_8 \ge x_9$ we retain $(x_{1} \cdots \overline{x_{8}})$, else we retain $( \overline{x_{9}} \cdots \overline{x_{16}})$. Etc.

Comment: I don't understand your solution, would you please explain it with example ?

Comment: why you use "must" word in your answer? why there is must one apt box ?

Comment: @MounaMokhiab This is why there must be an apt box: Either box $1$ is apt, or it isn't. If it is, we're done. If it isn't, then box $2$ must be strictly larger. Now, box $2$ is either apt or it isn't. If it is, then we're done, if it isn't then box $3$ must be larger, since $1$ was smaller. Repeat this until you get to the end. If box $30$ (and all before) are un-apt, then $31$ must be apt.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can solve the problem for 32 boxes with 9 openings: Let the boxes be numbered 1, 2, ..., 32.  Let the values in the boxes be $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_{32}$.

Preliminary observations:

(1) We are looking for a box whose value is a local maximum (i.e., whose value is greater than or equal to each of its immediate neighbors' value).  We understand that a local maximum may also occur at an end box if that end box's value is greater than or equal to its one neighbor.

(2) At least one local maximum must occur among the $32$ boxes.  (For instance the box with the absolute maximum value will also contain a local maximum.)

Steps:
(1) Open boxes 16 and 17.  If $a_{16}\ge a_{17}$ we will confine our remaining search to boxes 1 through 16.  If $a_{16}<a_{17}$ we will confine our remaining search to boxes 1 through 8. Let's say, without loss of generality that $a_{16}\ge a_{17}$.  Note that we may now restrict ourselves to boxes 1 to 16, with box 16 only needing to have a value greater than that of box 15 (since we already looked in box 17).  Thus we have an analogous problem but with the row of boxes 1 to 16.

(2) Open boxes 8 and 9.  The same sort of thing happens as in step 1.  Let's say $a_8\ge a_9$.  Now we will confine our remaining search to boxes 1 through 8.

(3)  Open boxes 4 and 5.  And again you can halve the number of boxes under consideration.  Again let's assume that $a_4\ge a_5$.

(4) Open boxes 2 and 3.  If say $a_2\ge a_3$, we can now know there will be a local maximum in box 1 or 2.

(5) Open box 1 to find out.

Comment: I think you run into some issues when you have equality in each comparison.

Comment: Dear @angryavian, there is no problem with equality, I think.

Comment: I think it's ok because the maximum can be non-strict (i.e., if three consecutive boxes had equal values, the middle one would be suitable.  Or if two consecutive were equal, and a box on one side were lower, like 10, 10, 8 or 7, 11, 11 the middle box would still be suitable.

Comment: @paw88789 You are absolutely right, I apologize.

Comment: @angryavian: No apology needed.

Answer (score 0):

Start by opening boxes 1, 8, 16, 23, 31. Now try showing that it is possible to restrict your search to one of the intervals [1, 16], [16, 31] - This will involve checking some simple cases.

So say we are in [1, 16] and we know the content of box 8. With this information, we can even narrow down to one of the subintervals [1, 8], [8, 16] unless $B(1) < B(8)$ and $B(8) > B(16)$ in which case, like above, we look at 5, 12 and restrict ourselves to say [1, 8] with the content of box 5 known. Assume again that $B(1) < B(5)$ and $B(5) > B(8)$. Now look at box 4. If $B(4) > B(5)$, we look in [1, 4] otherwise in [5, 8]. Now we can open all (two) boxes and win.

This took only 10 views so it is good enough.